# Implementing event logging in Corona SDK

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

I just started to use Corona sdk to make a simple game, I'm at the middle stage which is to implement event logging. I wanted to measure the time the players took before they press play.  I found tutorials about handling time and dates in some tutorials but how about recording time? For example, what if i want to record the time starting from opening the app until the player presses a button? Can anyone give me advice on how to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the begining of main.lua insert

```
local startTime = os.time()
```

and in the button touch event place

```
print("time from start: ", (os.time() - startTime))
```

and it should print it to the console